# Canvas, javascript interaction?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, diagram, interaction

As a part of a course in school, we're learning to work with the Canvas element of HTML5, this also means we're learning how to work with Javascript. The assignment is to create something graphic and some sort of interaction with this something graphic.

I decided to create a few simple diagrams and have the user be able to input values and see as the diagrams change.

http://people.dsv.su.se/~tojo0551/graf/lines.html contains a few diagrams I've drawn up, now comes the tricky part- working with Javascript and creating interaction. This is probably easy, but I never touched Javascript aside from JQuery before thus a bit at loss.

Say I want the user to be able to interact with the bar diagram at the bottom and to fill in a value between 1-5 and have the bar grow accordingly.

The Canvas code is simple, it looks like this:

```
function bars(){

var canvas = document.getElementById("bars");
if (canvas.getContext)
{   

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var bar1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
bar1.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .2)";
bar1.fillRect(20, 400, 30, 90);

var bar2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
bar2.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .4)";
bar2.fillRect(55, 360, 30, 130);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .2)";
ctx.fillRect(90, 260, 30, 230);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .4)";
ctx.fillRect(125, 290, 30, 200);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .2)";
ctx.fillRect(160, 270, 30, 220);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .4)";
ctx.fillRect(195, 250, 30, 240);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .2)";
ctx.fillRect(230, 300, 30, 190);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .2)";
ctx.fillRect(20, 400, 30, 90);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .4)";
ctx.fillRect(55, 360, 30, 130);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .2)";
ctx.fillRect(90, 260, 30, 230);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .4)";
ctx.fillRect(125, 290, 30, 200);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .2)";
ctx.fillRect(160, 270, 30, 220);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .4)";
ctx.fillRect(195, 250, 30, 240);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 50, 0, .2)";
ctx.fillRect(230, 300, 30, 190);
```

But where do I go from here? I am new to programming, I know how to create functions and control flow with selection and loops, you know, I am a beginner programmer. What is the natural path to go to create user control? I want some input before I start working so I don't work in the wrong direction. Any pages that have good advice on how to or any ideas you got are very welcome. 
/Tomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward.  If you have some experience of jQuery, I would suggest including it here, it would make things simpler.

Assuming you do use jQuery, you just need to call your bars() function whenever the user changes a value in an html input.  First just change your bars() declaration so that it can be called with a value.  Like this:

```
function bars(userVal) {
    // All your existing code ...
}
```

Then you will need to clear whatever was drawn last time bars() was called.  Something like:

```
function bars(userVal) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("bars");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        // Clear the bars that were drawn last time
        ctx.clearRect(x,y,w,h);
        // The rest of your existing code ...
    }
}
```

clearRect takes an origin location (x and y) and a height and a width (w and h), and will clear the canvas in that area.  So pass in the necessary limits of the drawing area.

Next add a text input to your page, and use jQuery to call bars() whenever it's changed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").on("change", function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        bars(value);
    });
});
```

Finally, you must decide what you want to do with the value the user has entered.  This is entirely up to you, but I guess a quick and easy test to check it will work is just to use a numerical value in one of the drawing calls.

Examples:

```
// This would change the start position of a bar
ctx.fillRect(userVal, 260, 30, 230);
// This would change the width of a bar
ctx.fillRect(90, 260, userVal, 230);
// This would change the colour of a bar
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(userVal, 50, 0, .4)";
```

Have fun.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I get the idea of it all. However, not allowed to use JQuery for this assignment. I am wondering, is it considered good or bad practice to mix Javascript and JQuery?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, it's written in javascript ... i.e. you cannot have jQuery without javascript.  jQuery is a very widely used library, it's incredibly easy to pick up, and very powerful.  I use it on the vast majority of web applications I build.

Comment: Yes, my thought was more of a do you write JavaScript 100% when starting to write in JavaScript or do you write some JavaScript and then add a few JQuery snippets of code for any reason? When writing an application in JQuery, do you ever write pure JavaScript.. but that's not important, really. I got it all working now, it needs some styling and some user friendly-ness but it's all good. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/).  It begins to get very complicated to do relatively simple things using canvas, and this seems to make life easier in general though it supports interaction as well.  It's important to know the fundamentals, but don't try to build a house without your carpentry tools.

If plotting is what interests you more, you should take a look at [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).

Then for the adventurous amongst us, there's [three](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) which plots 3d.  Though you should work up to that.